# Android: What would be an 'elegant' way to modify this library?

Tags: java, android, api

**Background**

I have access to the source of a library I'm using for audio recording/analysis and need to modify it for my application.

There is a main activity (class A) in which I set up views and stuff. The library has a class (class B) that handles raw audio data from the microphone using Audio Recorder. An instance of that class is run as a task through another class (class C) that extends AsyncTask, of which the main activity has an instance.

So class A has an instance of class C, class C has an instance of class B and class B has the raw data I want to access from class A.

**Why?**

I want to call an activity that displays a graph with raw data found in class B.

**What I tried**

I added a method to get the raw data in class B and call it from class C. Now I could create a similar method in class C so that class A can get raw data from class C. That, however, makes me want to puke.

Another way could be to call the graphing activity from class C itself, but I feel I'm adding logic that doesn't belong to that class.

I want a nice way to implement this, but have no background in design patterns nor much common sense. Help would really be appreciated here.

/E

Comment: Not knowing the structure of these classes, it sounds like you should be directly calling class B for this data if it's the class containing said data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct OO way is, as you have described it:

- add a method getRawData to class B
- add a method getRecordedAudio to class C

**Explanation**

Even though, it may at first seems arkward, it is the correct object oriented way, because, that way you will later be able to access the raw data from class B using that method also from any other class (say class D) without the need to think up of additional logic again.

Also, it may be possible that you need to run that Async task (C) from another activity (say E). In that case you can savely reuse getRecordedAudio without the need to reinvent the wheel.

**Final notes**

From what you have explained about your API this is best way I can come up with. If there are any other limitations, you need to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

What's about the good old [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Your Class B would be the Observable that needs a method to register Observers. A and C would be both Observers that will register with B, they both have a method to be notified.

If there are any changes in the data of an instance of B, it will call the notify method for all registered objects A and C and they can react on it seperately.

I think if the sources are available that's the most elegant way to accomplish your task. Have a look on the wiki link for further information on what you would need to implement the pattern, but in general it's quite straight forward.